# Django "NameError: name 'Album' not defined"

Tags: python, django, database, model-view-controller, model

I am trying to run see and manipulate a simple django database but the error from the Django Shell is saying one of my models isn't defined.

Most of the questions with errors similar to mine are due to people referencing a model before declaring it.  However, I'm not referencing any other model in **Album**.

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

The error I am getting:
[NameError: name 'Album' is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5tFi.png)

Any idea what could the the cause of this error?

For reference, I'm following thenewboston's django tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYTiPwEGKyQ&index=9&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open your shell, it is just a python shell without anything from your app imported.

You should import your models first:

```
from your_app_name.models import Album
```

If you don't want to import your models every time, use [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) which will load them for you. Use `shell_plus` command:

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Late to respond, but thanks for the reply.  I installed the django extensions, added it to the installed apps, and am now able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this--

```
class Song(models.Model):
album = models.ForeignKey('app_name.Album', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write album in quotes and see like this

```
album = models.ForeignKey("Album", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

album = models.ForeignKey('Album', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

This worked for me!